# Does a 4x8 sheet of 1/4'' pegboard need support across the middle of the board?

Tags: storage

Simple question, I'm hanging some pegboard in my garage tonight after work, and am not sure if I can get away with just screwing the edges into 2x4 (I'm using thicker boards to accommodate a recessed outlet behind it that powers a lamp above it and power bar to the side) boarder, or if I need additional studs throughout the pegboard. If I do need additional studs, would one laterally mounted in the middle screwed into the existing wall studs be sufficient?

For reference, this will hold metal hand tools only, I store my power tools (drills, reciprocating saws, etc) in the cases they came in underneath the workbench.

Comment: Is this the pressed cardboard-like pegboard, or something more sturdy?

Comment: You probably want to put the spacers behind it in the middle to avoid bowing, just put those at the studs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The board should hold the weight you describe vertically. The board will probably bow a little bit naturally even without tools on it.  I would add the extra stud because it's cheap, easy, and better to do things right the first time.

I think 2" x 4" studs are a bit over-kill here.  You could probably use 2" x 2" boards to make it lighter (easier to mount) and not stick out from the wall so much.

Pre-drill all your screw holes.  If you try and screw into it near the edges without pre-drilling, the board could tear.  That sounds bad; it really isn't, just looks noticeable.